# Block all referer request on Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, spam-prevention, mod-rewrite

I use my Apache server for a B2B application and I want to block all the referer requests like this one :

```
[Tue Aug 13 14:23:05 2013] [error] [client 74.63.192.51] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/newServing, referer: http://www.bestthemoney.com/a/2012/04/09
```

Is theire any way to block all the requests that start with `referer` ?

Answer (score 0):

Referer is the site from the referer header on the request, not the request.  I do not believe you want to do what you are asking how to do.

You can use the rewrite engine to block specific referers, if they are causing problems.  This is usually applied to graphics, css files, and other resources.

You will at least need to allow requests without a referer, or that are refered from your own site.  It is most likely you want to allow others to link to you site so you also want to allow links to at least the entry pages of your site.  Also, be aware that it is easy to spoof the referer header.

You Apache server will normally respond with a 404 message to requests like this.  Do check your site to ensure that the requests are not for pages missing from your site.  In this case, it appears `newServing` is the path being searched for.

Check your access log for URLs with a `404` status code.

If you do want to block or redirect pages, read the [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).